# WinRT C++ IMap returning Windows Runtime Object instead of IDictionary into C#

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, .net-4.5, c++-cx, winrt-async

We have a problem with a C++ Backend Library for our C# Windows Store Application.

On the C++ side we have a property that is defined like this:

```
property IMap<String^, IMap<String^, String^>^ >^   myVariable;
```

On the C# side the property is correctly transformed to:

```
public IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, string>> myVariable { get; set; }
```

The situation: while in debug (with a breakpoint set), you can see that the returned object from C++ is a Windows Runtime Object, instead of the expected Dictionary. I can iterate through the returned object and the code in the foreach loop executes successfully.

[image: Windows Runtime Object in Debug]

The problem: if I remove the breakpoint (but I am still in debug), the returned object does not have any information. It is not null, as I get no exception, but it is empty (the foreach loop does not execute -- the inner breakpoint is not reached).

More information:

- the Dictionary itself is part of a larger object;
- the rest of the properties contain information;
- in a C++ Windows Store Application the Dictionary (IMap) is correctly displayed (so the problem may be from the linking between C++ and C#);
- I get the backend object using async Tasks:

`BiggerObject myObject = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    return _clientInstance.GetMyObject(key);
});`

Do you have any ideas why the Dictionary is not correctly recognized while in Debug and why it is empty while not in Debug?

Thank you for your answers!

Regards,
Ionut

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me.

Simple C++ code:

**Header**

```
public ref class MapOfMapsTest sealed
{
public:
  MapOfMapsTest();
  property IMap<String^, IMap<String^, String^>^>^ Stuff;
};
```

**Implementation**

```
MapOfMapsTest::MapOfMapsTest()
{
  auto outerMap = ref new Platform::Collections::Map<String^, IMap<String^, String^>^>();
  auto innerMap = ref new Platform::Collections::Map<String^, String^>();
  innerMap->Insert(L"1", L"one");
  innerMap->Insert(L"3", L"three");
  outerMap->Insert(L"odd", innerMap);

  innerMap = ref new Platform::Collections::Map<String^, String^>();
  innerMap->Insert(L"2", L"two");
  innerMap->Insert(L"4", L"four");
  outerMap->Insert(L"even", innerMap);

  Stuff = outerMap;
}
```

Simple C# code (where `lv` is a `ListView` declared in the XAML)

```
private void DoMapThing()
{
  var test = new MapOfMapsTest();
  foreach (var k in test.Stuff.Keys)
  {
    var innerDict = test.Stuff[k];
    foreach (var k2 in innerDict.Keys)
      lv.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} -> {1} : {2}", k, k2, innerDict[k2]));
  }
}
```